# How do we read $x∈[0,50]$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do we read $x∈[0,50]$?

Should we read it as "$x$ is an element of the set $0$ to $50$"?

I tried to search the answer but I couldn't find how to read the set.

Thank you.

Comment: Of the [*interval*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)) (extremes included).

Comment: x in zero fifty

Comment: "$x$ is an element of the closed interval from zero to fifty."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above representation is interpreted as "$x$ belongs to the closed interval $[0,50]$" which can be mathematically interpreted as $0 \le x \le 50$.